# Kendo Upload with complex obejct as data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, upload, xmlhttprequest, kendo-upload

I've read [this post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/async-kendoupload-pass-custom-arguments-or-additional-data-to-mvc-controller) but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there really no way to pass data or am I missing something?

**C#**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ApiMethod(Person person) 
{
    //...do stuff
}
```

**javascript**

```
$("#files").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: 'www.api.com/controller/ApiMethod',
        autoUpload: true,
    },
    upload: function (e) {
        e.data = { 
            person: {
                FirstName: "First",
                LastName: "Last",
            },
        };
    },
});
```

When I check the Network tab in developer tools, I don't see any data being passed through.

Comment: I don't get it are you trying to upload a document along with additional metadata for that document. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Kinda. If it were ajax: `$.ajax({data: {FirstName: "first, LastName: "Last",},});`